# What's the difference between free and premium version of Aldiko Book Reader?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, aldiko

When it comes to epub format ebooks reading, [Aldiko Book Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) is the best Android app on Earth and nobody will oppose it, as I think. I have been using it for 5 months and really satisfied. Now, I am thinking about purchasing its [premium version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.aldiko) in hope to get more useful features. But, I am unable to find what I'll get new with premium version. Its page on Play Store doesn't have anything about "Premium Exclusive Features". Please, help if you've used premium version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is in their [FAQ](https://aldiko.zendesk.com/entries/403921-what-s-the-difference-between-the-free-version-aldiko-app-and-the-premium-version-aldiko-app):

> The free version is advertisement supported while the premium version
>   is not. Both the free and premium versions have the same set of
>   features at this point except the premium version will get faster
>   updates.

Comment: Faster updates are digestible, but I've never found ads in free version. Means, I'll not get any additional feature with premium version.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Maybe you're right. I also use the FREE version.

Comment: you can't use highlighter in free version